# fopen alternatives for curl CURLOPT_INFILE

Tags: php, curl, fopen

Unfortunately, my server has forbidden `fopen()`. What could I use instead? 
Here is my script:

```
$fp = fopen($path, 'r');  
$ch = curl_init('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cheaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$contents = utf8_encode($server_output);
$results = json_decode($contents);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Are you sure `fopen` is disabled? Or are you trying to access a file outside of a path allowed by an [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restriction?

Comment: yes i'm sure,
 fopen is disabled as my work is for SugarCRM and it has blacklisted some PHP functions.
I fond its solution using sugar_file_get_contents() and it works fine for me thanks !